# filter is not a function error in jQuery code

Tags: jquery

I have this jQuery code, but whenever I invoke the `filter` method on the `data` variable in my Ajax callback I get an error stating

> data.filter is not a function

I have also tried replacing `filter` with `find`, with similar results. If I just use `.html(data)`, the markup in the `data` variable is successfully added to my page. However, since I only need a portion of the markup, I need to be able to filter by the `.allMessages` class selector prior to adding that markup to the page.

```
$('body').on('click','.page-link',function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();

       var url = $(this).attr("href");
       glob = url;
       $.get(url,{type:'jquery'},function (data) {
            filter = data.filter('.allMessages');
           $("#contentMessage").html(filter).show('fast');
             targetUrl =glob;
           window.history.pushState({url: "" + targetUrl + ""},glob , targetUrl);
       });
   });
```

Here, `data` is an HTML string of the format

```
<html>
  ...
</html>
```

I've validated the structure of that HTML using `console.log(data)` and `$("contentMessage").text(data).show('fast')`, and was able to validate that the full HTML text is included, including a `<div>` element with the desired `allMessages` class.

After logging `$(data).filter('.allMessages')` to the console, I got a jQuery object of length 0 (no matched elements).

Why am I getting this error, and how can I resolve this?

Answer (score 4):

The (first) parameter to [`$.get`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/#jQuery-get1)'s callback function isn't a jQuery object, so you can't invoke jQuery methods on that variable. In this case, it's a DOM string. The simplest solution is to wrap it in a call to the jQuery object to get a jQuery object instance:

```
$(data).filter('.allMessages');
```

Depending on the specific format of that data, though, you may want to parse that separately before wrapping it in the jQuery object.

---

However, based on the text you are getting back for `data`, you should be using [`find`](https://api.jquery.com/find) in this case:

```
$(data).find('.allMessages');
```

[`filter`](https://api.jquery.com/filter) looks at elements in the jQuery object, and removes the ones that don't match the provided selector. It does not traverse the DOM to look at the elements children -- it simply matches against the top-level element in the jQuery object.

`find` traverses elements in the matched set, and returns a jQuery object containing the descendants matching the selector -- which is what you'd like, in this case.

Comment: tried it but i do get an object not the html markup

Comment: @spartyboy The fact that [`.html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2) works for you means that `data` is an html string. You can try printing it with `console.log` to validate that.

Comment: still the same problem

Comment: when i logged it i got an object response

Comment: this is how i did it console.log($(data).filter('.allMessages'));

Answer (score 1):

Response data must be jquery obj to use filter method. I think you can try

```
$(data).filter('.allMessages');
```